# Ionic ui-router

Tags: angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am having an issue using the ui-router with ionic tabs.

When I attempt to transition to a state that is nested within a tab from a separate tab it appears to resolve it in the stateProvider, in terms of entering the resolve statements, but never actually enters the state.

The applicable states are here:

```
   .state('index', {
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl:'app/main.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('index.got', {
        url: "/got",
        views: {
            'got-tab': {
                templateUrl: "app/got/main.html",
                controller: 'GotCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('index.got.listing', {
        url: "/listings/:id",
        templateUrl: "app/got/listing/listing.html",
        controller: "GotListingCtrl",
        resolve: {
            listing: function(Listing, $stateParams) {
                return Listing.get({id: $stateParams.id});
            }
        },
    })
    .state('index.feed', {
      url: "/feed",
      views: {
        'feed-tab': {
             templateUrl: "app/home/feed/feed.html",
             controller: 'FeedCtrl',
             resolve: {
                listings: function(CurrentUser) {
                    return CurrentUser.feed()
                }
            }
        }
      }
```

And the tabs

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-color-positive tabs-icon-top">
    <ion-tab title="Got" ui-sref="index.got.listings">
        <ion-nav-view name="got-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
    <ion-tab title="Home" ui-sref="index.feed">
        <ion-nav-view name="feed-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

The call I make to transfer states is

```
    var index = $state.get('index')
    $state.transitionTo('.got.listing', {id: '1'}, {relative: index})
```

I assume the issue is because I am dealing with nested names views, but any help would be much appreciated thanks

Comment: For anyone interested, I ended up pre-routing to the specified tab (not visible to user) before routing to the end state that I wanted.  I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but this still works, just a little more work.

Answer (score 0):

your resolves Should just be returning the Parameter Information for the current state, so for listing tab:

```
.state('index.got.listing', {
    url: '/listings/:id,
    templateUrl: '/app/got/listing/listing.html',
    controller: 'GotListingCtrl',
    resolve: {
        listing: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
            return $stateParams.id;
        }]
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response...but it wasn't the resolve that was breaking the transition.  And there are actually many times where you would use a resolve like I did above...if you actually need the object before you make the view switch to do some logic or something.  I think it was just an issue with older versions of ionic though because it seems to be fixed now.